# How chan bool is making goroutine waiting?

Tags: go

I'm building an app to run a command every time the code changes. I'm using a `fsnotify` for this feature. But, I can't understand how it is waiting a main goroutine.

I found that using `sync.WaitGroup` is more idiomatic, but I'm curious how done chan bool makes a goroutine is waiting in `fsnotify` example code.

I've tried to remove `done` in the example code of `fsnotify`, but it's not waiting a goroutine, just is exited.

```golang
watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer watcher.Close()

done := make(chan bool)
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case event, ok := <-watcher.Events:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            log.Println("event:", event)
            if event.Op&fsnotify.Write == fsnotify.Write {
                log.Println("modified file:", event.Name)
            }
        case err, ok := <-watcher.Errors:
            if !ok {
                return
            }
            log.Println("error:", err)
        }
    }
}()

err = watcher.Add("/tmp/foo")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
<-done
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Your code is broken. Are you asking why it's broken?

Comment: This code is not broken, this code is just I copy & paste from `fsnotify` example.

https://godoc.org/github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify#example-NewWatcher

And I checked it's running.

Comment: No, it is broken. The `done` channel is unused. It should be closed somewhere, but it isn't. Whether you copied and pasted it is irrelevant. The code _is_ broken.

Comment: You can say that. But the point you say `broken` is the key of this logic. I'm not sure if you check out `fsnotify` or not, actually `<-done` makes keeping the main goroutine running and watcher can send a event to goroutine. Moreever, this code actually is working.

Comment: ... You can say that. But I assure you, the code is broken.

Comment: But that's beside the point. My question to you was: What is your question?

Comment: I've provided an "answer" explaining why your code is broken--and why it does what it does. I still don't understand what you're asking, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but there's a subtle bug in the code you've provided.

A `done` channel is a common way to block until an action completes. It is used like this:

```
done := make(chan X) // Where X is any type
go func() {
    // Some logic, possibly in a loop
    close(done)
}()
// Other logic
<-done // Wait for `done` to be closed
```

The type of the channel is unimportant, as no data is (necissarily) sent over the channel, so `bool` works, but `struct{}` is more idiomatic, as it indicates that no data can be sent.

Your example almost does this, except that it never calls `close(done)`. This is a bug. It means that the code will always wait forever at `<-done`, thus negating the entire purpose of a done channel. Your example code will *never exit*.

This means the code, as you have provided, could be also written as:

```
go func() {
    // Do stuff
}()
// Do other stuff
<Any code that blocks forever>
```

Because there are countless ways to block forever--none of them ever useful in practice--the channel in your example is not needed.

Answer (score -1):

As per my study, I found an answer from one guy in reddit.com. This is kind of trick though, using `<-done` makes the main goroutine waiting an any value from chan done, eventually this app keeps running for `fsnotify` to watch and send a event to the main goroutine.